# jms : unable to get hindi data from at cosumer side

Tags: java, utf-8, jms, activemq-classic

I have setup activemq for achieve jms with the help of java. I wrote simple program for Producer and Consumer. I can send hindi data (UTF-8) data. but when i tried to receive utf-8 data msg , getting garbage data. I am bit confuse where to set its character encoding.

Producer Send - "हैलो रोहित"

Consumer Receive - "????? ??????" (UTF -8 issue).
I am loosing character encoding of data. How to apply or get UTF- 8 data.

Note : xx.xx.xx.xx:8161/admin if browse i can see status of each queue which i have created. even that hindi msg also displys properly.

snapshot of Producer Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
        new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("user", "password", "tcp://xx.xx.xx.xxx:61616");
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false,
        Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Destination destination = session.createQueue("NewQueue");
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("हैलो रोहित");
    producer.send(message);
    System.out.println("Sent message '" + message.getText() + "'");
    connection.close();
}
```

Snapshot of Consumer code :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
   // Getting JMS connection from the server
   ConnectionFactory connectionFactory
        = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("user", "password", "tcp://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:61616");
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    // Creating session for sending messages
    Session session = connection.createSession(false,
        Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Destination destination = session.createQueue("NewQueue");
    // MessageConsumer is used for receiving (consuming) messages
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
    Message message = consumer.receive();
    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        System.out.println("Received message '"
            + textMessage.getText() + "'");
    }
    connection.close();
}
```

Comment: how about `new String(textMessage.getText().getBytes (), "UTF-8")`

Comment: Thanks Scary wombat. I tried but its not working for this, Actually in textMessage object it already got garbage data.

Comment: Try to send BytesMessage and do a manual conversion on receiver side. Also, please post producer-side code that is sending that hindi string.

Comment: Thanks Miljenko, I tried this too. but getting chunk data like this " à¤¹à¥ˆà¤²à¥‹ à¤°à¥‹à¤¹à¤¿". producer side code updated. :)

Comment: Did you try using UTF-8 while creating this message in Hindi in the Producer code.   Producer should convert to bytes using HindliString.getBytes(String charsetName)  and Consumer should read bytesmessages and convert bytes to String using   public String(byte[] bytes,
              String charsetName)

Comment: @Amrish. Thanks for reply. I did it but same junk data displays.

Comment: Problem solved but still confuse. Actually I just add hindi data to print like `System.out.println("हैलो");` // in consumer side code. while saving file, I got Save Problem alert message. Warning was : Save could not be completed. Try File> Save As... if the problem persist.. Reason : some characters cant be mapped using cp1252 character encoding" There were 3 buttons ok , save as UTF-8 and select first character." -> and I just save it as UTF-8. and problem solved.